# Warning 6 while loading data to MSSQLSpatial using ogr2ogr

Tags: gdal, ogr2ogr, sql-server-spatial

I am loading layers from a .gdb to a database in SQL Server using the following command:

```
ogr2ogr -f MSSQLSpatial "MSSQL:server=server_name;database=database_name;trusted_connection=yes" "gdbsourcelocation" -a_srs "EPSG:4326" -lco "GEOM_TYPE=geography" -lco "GEOM_NAME=geog4326" -progress
```

This fails with the following warning:

```
Warning 6: Linestring has no points. Removing the geometry from the output.
```

Even when I use `-skipfailures`  it fails.

Comment: Does the input data look correct with `ogrinfo gdbsourcelocation -al`?

Comment: yes things look okay. I have a lot of layers so it's hard to pinpoint the issue.

Comment: Try if conversion into GeoPackage succeeds: `ogr2ogr -f gpkg test.gpkg gdbsourcelocation -a_srs EPSG:4326 -progress`. If it does then the issue may have something to do with MSSQL.